# Domain Change YouTube data API v3 won't work

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I changed the domain and name of my site. Renamed the email associated with the developers account in Google Domains. The YouTube API quit. I deleted it and created a new one with new credentials, but even those won't let me embed a link in my website anymore. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place for this question. Check out https://stackexchange.com/ for a more suitable forum.

Comment: This is where the Google Developers help section leads people.